# Swift problem with dismissing view and then present new one

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, delegates, protocols

I have TabBarViewController, when I click on his children, view is presented, which is called SettingsVC, inside SettingsVC I have tableview, which at the bottom has logout, when I click on logout, I would like to dismiss SettingsVC and present LoginVC, but I can't manage to implement this. I know I should use delegate, protocol, but I am doing something wrong. Code is below, thanks.

**Code below is from SettingsVC**

```
protocol PresentViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func presentViewController(vc: LogInViewController)
}

class SettingsVC: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    public var presentDelegate: PresentViewControllerDelegate?

    func present() {
        presentDelegate?.presentViewController(vc: LogInViewController())
    }

    func logoutUser() {
    networkManager.logout(endpoint: "/v1/auth/logout") { (session) in
        switch session {
        case .success:
            print(session)
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.present()
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
     }
 }

extension SettingsVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let settings = SettingsEnums(rawValue: indexPath.row)
    
    switch settings {
    case .passcode:
        print("passcode")
    case .about:
        print("about")
    case .termsAndConditions:
        print("terms and conditions")
    case .privacyPolicy:
        print("privacy policy")
    case .visit:
        print("visit")
    case .logout:
        logoutUser()
        print("logout clicked")
        
    default:
        print("default")
    }
  }
}
```

**And then I tried this in TabBarVC**

```
extension TabBarViewController: PresentViewControllerDelegate {
    func presentViewController(vc: LogInViewController) {
      self.present(self, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}

class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var settingsVC: SettingsVC!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()  
    settingsVC.presentDelegate = self
  }
}
```

I do have success in logout, and I manage to dismiss SettingsVC, but cannot manage to present LogInVC. If you think that this would have a delay and it could be visible that "exchange", please can you suggest some other solution?

I have hard time understanding delegates..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I can see: 1. you did not set the `delegate` to `TabBarViewController` 2. It should be `self.present(vc, ...)`, not `vc.present(self, ...)`.

Comment: @Sweeper hey, please can you check my question? its edited now, I did made some changes but still not working, what am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you would want to change the root view controller to loginVC instead of displaying login on top of tab bar.